# Contact Form 7 Passing data to Ajax thank you messege

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

For a few days now I am trying to pass data from the form to the thank you message with no success.

All i want to do is pass the [First-Name] field to the Ajax massage so it will be:

"[First-Name], Your message has been sent successfully"

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have tried this for some day, what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the First-Name into session and you call that session value in success page,

```
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'save_cf7_data');

function save_cf7_data($cf) 
{

    if(session_id() == '') {
       session_start();
    }

    $current_submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    $_SESSION['cf7_submission'] = $current_submission->get_posted_data();
}
```

and in success page you can call it like

```
echo $_SESSION['cf7_submission']['First-Name'].', Your message has been sent successfull';
```

here "First-Name" is the contact form 7 field name that you want to display in success page.

Comment: Ok but this is if i redirect to success page.
I want it to be without redirect to success page but in the AJAX success message.